# Creating hard and soft links using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, symlink

Can PowerShell 1.0 create hard and soft links analogous to the Unix variety?

If this isn't built in, can someone point me to a site that has a ps1 script that mimics this?

This is a necessary function of any good shell, IMHO. :)

Comment: Windows 10 users see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34905638/195755 .  
Windows 10 it **is** built-in.  Copy/Paste: `New-Item -Type ` and press tab to cycle through the options.  `Hardlink`, `SymbolicLink`, and `Junction` appear for me.
Works Win 10, Server 2016+, or older OS with Powershell 5.0+ installed via Windows Management Framework 5.0+.

Comment: I can't find decent MSDN/TechNet documentation for `New-Item -Type HardLink` nor `New-Item -Type SymbolicLink`.  New-Item docs link to `help about_Providers`, it suggests you read help for each provider (which isn't linked).  But if you google it there is plenty of buzz in the PowerShell community around `New-Item -Type HardLink`.
It looks like the PowerShell engineering team has come up with **provider** extension points that stump the docs team.

Comment: **`WARNING!`** -- While it is very easy to create *hardlinks*, it may be quite a challenge to remove them securely. That is because the tools are not easily available in native Powershell while Windows like to lock file access and keep files in memory (thus not always removable without a reboot.) Please see my post [here](https://superuser.com/a/1590780/).

Comment: Can we consider removing the version 1.0 from the question? With the number of votes I'd bet 99.9% of folks hitting this page are NOT don't care about 1.0.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can call the `mklink` provided by `cmd`, from PowerShell to make symbolic links:

```
cmd /c mklink c:\path\to\symlink c:\target\file
```

You must pass `/d` to `mklink` if the target is a directory.

```
cmd /c mklink /d c:\path\to\symlink c:\target\directory
```

For hard links, I suggest something like [Sysinternals Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx).

Comment: If you have a powershell profile, you can also make a quick function `function mklink {
    cmd /c mklink $args
}`

Comment: and if you want to make a directory link, the command will be something like { cmd /c mklink /D "toDir" fromDir }

Comment: adding the /H parameter to mklink will create a hard link without the need for a third party program like Sysinternals Junction.

Comment: I think jocassid has the better answer. IMHO, We should try to teach how to USE PowerShell, not use exploits and hacks through cmd.exe.

Comment: @CameronOakenleaf I agree whole-heartedly.

Comment: it won't work in PowerShell when trying to access symbolic link as cd c:\path\to\symlink. PowerShell cmdlet: NewItem -Path c:\link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value D:\target\file works

Comment: @SergeVoloshenko It [sure does](https://gist.github.com/fa4278b3738c8f0b0680aaf9237b6f47). True, using `New-Item` [does detect if the target is a directory](https://gist.github.com/d6b38f78a078afe8c734226d6040b3d7), but `New-Item` [will fail if the target does not exist](https://gist.github.com/3b75396b4fc51f863a9434cec446cd95) whereas [mklink will create the symbolic link regardless](https://gist.github.com/9f2ea76f1539163b45c4e033a4f67d2a).

Comment: and using /j parameter instead of /h, makes a directory junction where the source folder (link) will always appear as the source folder to all applications.  Using /d entering via the source folder (link) will then jump to and appear as the real target folder, which is a problem if storing paths shared in team environments.

Answer (score 439):

**Windows 10 (and Powershell 5.0 in general) allows you to [create symbolic links via the New-Item cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item).**

Usage:

```
New-Item -Path C:\LinkDir -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value F:\RealDir
```

Or in your profile:

```
function make-link ($target, $link) {
    New-Item -Path $link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $target
}
```

Turn on **Developer Mode** to not require admin privileges when making links with `New-Item`:

[image]

Comment: This link is now broken due to MS rearranging documentation. I found a current working link at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx

Comment: New-Item -Path C:\LinkDir -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value F:\RealDir

Comment: since Windows v1703, mklink allows creating symlinks without account elevation, if Developer mode is enabled in Settings, New-Item doesn't. Hopefully in next update.

Comment: Fascinating. So this is quite distinct from an Explorer `.lnk` shortcut. In explorer, a shortcut and symlink of the same name display side by side as if nothing was amiss. Their behaviors are subtly different; following the symlink shows the absolute path in the Explorer bar. Following the shortcut treats it as if the symlink parent dir is the true parent.

Comment: With the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/creating-hard-and-soft-links-using-powershell/5549583#5549583), I was able to use relative paths, which wasn't the case with the `New-Item` commandlet.

Comment: New-Item allows an `-ItemType` of `HardLink` for a file and `Junction` for a directory. These do not require developer mode or admin privileges.

Comment: Also note that this solution works on Linux  system too. `New-Item -Path /opt/link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value /usr/local/bin`

Comment: I can't turn on developer mode for my work laptop.

Answer (score 48):

## Add "pscx" module

No, it isn't built into PowerShell. And the `mklink` utility cannot be called on its own on Windows Vista/Windows 7 because it is [built directly into `cmd.exe` as an "internal command"](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

You can use the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) (free). There are several cmdlets for reparse points of various types:

- `New-HardLink`,
- `New-SymLink`,
- `New-Junction`,
- `Remove-ReparsePoint`
- and others.

Comment: Good try. Though if you want to run XP or W2K3 server in either x32 or x64, New-Symlink dosen't work. In XP it will politely tell you that you should be running Vista for this command. In W2K3 server, it flat out breaks.

Comment: That's because XP doesn't support symlinks. That's a feature new to Vista.  I believe that W2K3 server doesn't support symlinks either.  You have to step up to W2K8 server to get symlink support.  I'll look into why new-symlink is bombing on W2k3, it should error with a similar message to XP.

Comment: I tried new-junction and that will work for me. Too bad the link functionality doesn't degrade to junctions in XP and W2K3

Comment: on further use of new-junction... I get a junction to the new parse point. However ls (or get-childitem) errors stating that.."The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" If I try and enter a subdirectory from there.

Comment: Windows 10 users see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34905638/195755 .  
Windows 10 it *is* built-in.  Copy/Paste: `New-Item -Type ` and press tab to cycle through the options.  `Hardlink`, `SymbolicLink`, and `Junction` appear for me.
Works Win 10, Server 2016+, or older OS with Powershell 5.0 installed via Windows Management Framework 5.0+.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, please see @jocassid's answer.

Comment: Answer kinda broken now (2019). Because by now PSCX commands clash with native PowerShell commands. And PSCX requires workarounds to even install. => https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/issues/23 (And that ticket has been unfixed since 2017. So I don't expect a real fix anytime soon.)

Comment: Agreed.  **Ten** years ago this made sense but yeah, PowerShell has finally added built-in commands for this functionality.  :-)

Answer (score 28):

In Windows 7, the command is

```
fsutil hardlink create new-file existing-file
```

PowerShell finds it without the full path (c:\Windows\system32) or extension (.exe).

Comment: `fsutil hardlink` requires `new-file` and `existing-file` to be on the same drive. If that matters to you, use cmd's `mklink /c` instead.

Comment: @mopsled Hardlinks, by definition, must be on the same volume as the target, this is not a limitation specific to `fsutil` (or Windows for that matter)

Comment: is there an equivalent for "soft" symlinks and junctions?

Comment: Worked also on a Windows10 system.

Answer (score 15):

New-Symlink:

```
Function New-SymLink ($link, $target)
{
    if (test-path -pathtype container $target)
    {
        $command = "cmd /c mklink /d"
    }
    else
    {
        $command = "cmd /c mklink"
    }

    invoke-expression "$command $link $target"
}
```

Remove-Symlink:

```
Function Remove-SymLink ($link)
{
    if (test-path -pathtype container $link)
    {
        $command = "cmd /c rmdir"
    }
    else
    {
        $command = "cmd /c del"
    }

    invoke-expression "$command $link"
}
```

Usage:

```
New-Symlink "c:\foo\bar" "c:\foo\baz"
Remove-Symlink "c:\foo\bar"
```

Comment: Windows 10 users see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34905638/195755 .  
Windows 10 it *is* built-in.  Copy/Paste: `New-Item -Type ` and press tab to cycle through the options.  `Hardlink`, `SymbolicLink`, and `Junction` appear for me.
Works Win 10, Server 2016+, or older OS with Powershell 5.0 installed via Windows Management Framework 5.0+.

Comment: Or if the file name contains them.

Answer (score 12):

## Try junction.exe

The [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) command line utility from SysInternals makes creating and deleting junctions easy.

## Further reading

- **MS Terminology: soft != symbolic**
  Microsoft uses *"soft link"* as another name for *"junction"*.
  However: a *"symbolic link"* is something else entirely.
  See MSDN: [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006(VS.85).aspx) in Windows.
  (This is in direct contradiction to the general usage of those terms where *"soft link"* and *"symbolic link"* (*"symlink"*) [DO mean the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).)

Comment: The use of this utility correctly allows me to junction another directory and traverse it's subdirectories successfully. All in XP and W2K3. Just add the exe to a directory in your PATH and call it like normal.

Comment: I don't think you can use junction.exe to create symbolic links.

Comment: It´s better to use `mklink` which is shipped with Windows. *If* you have a Windows version which it is shipped with.

Answer (score 7):

I combined two answers (@bviktor and @jocassid). It was tested on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012.

```
function New-SymLink ($link, $target)
{
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5)
    {
        New-Item -Path $link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $target
    }
    else
    {
        $command = "cmd /c mklink /d"
        invoke-expression "$command ""$link"" ""$target"""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this utility:

```
c:\Windows\system32\fsutil.exe create hardlink
```

Comment: It will require elevated privileges, though. Creating hardlinks usually doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a PowerShell module that has native wrappers for MKLINK. https://gist.github.com/2891103

Includes functions for:

- New-Symlink
- New-HardLink
- New-Junction

Captures the MKLINK output and throws proper PowerShell errors when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals) `junction` command only works with directories (don't ask me why), so it can't hardlink files. I would go with `cmd /c mklink` for soft links (I can't figure why it's not supported directly by PowerShell), or `fsutil` for hardlinks.

If you need it to work on Windows XP, I do not know of anything other than Sysinternals `junction`, so you might be limited to directories.

Answer (score -2):

I found this the simple way without external help.  Yes, it uses an archaic DOS command but it works, it's easy, and it's clear.

```
$target = cmd /c dir /a:l | ? { $_ -match "mySymLink \[.*\]$" } | % `
{
    $_.Split([char[]] @( '[', ']' ), [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
}
```

This uses the DOS dir command to find all entries with the symbolic link attribute, filters on the specific link name followed by target "[]" brackets, and for each - presumably one - extracts just the target string.

Comment: Is this an answer for a different question?