# How do you get visual studio 2010 to remember custom xml schemas

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I'm working on a project with a couple of custom xsd schemas. They are only used every once in a while and every time I come to write something I have to re-add the schemas in the xml menu to get intellisense.

Inbetween uses they don't change location/content and the installed version isn't modified (the schemas ship with an internal library which hasn't been changed for ages).  The schemas are installed locally in program files. I work as part of a team that uses version control (hg) and the schemas aren't versioned along with the code - as mentioned before they are part of a separate library.

Is there any way to get visual studio 2010 to remember them in between sessions/does anyone know why I might be losing them every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put your schema files in the following directory:
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas

Comment: Cheers that seems to work.  In combination with symbolic links [see wiki article on links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Windows_7_.26_Vista_symbolic_link) (didn't realise windows could do these) and [this page on how to get mklink to work with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/powershell-hard-and-soft-links) I managed to avoid having to copy them across if the schemas get updated aswell