# How to create a link without .lnk extension?

Tags: windows, hyperlink, path, lnk

If I have a file named "C\Test\mypic.jpg", can I create a shortcut with path "C\Test2\mypic.jpg"? Windows always seems to add a ".lnk" suffix, which is unwanted in my case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link in this case can mean several things but we can unpack all the possible scenarios:

- A shortcut (.lnk file). These files must have the .lnk extension because the file extension is how Windows decides which handler to invoke when you double-click/execute the file. If you create a shortcut to a jpg file the real name can be `link.jpg.lnk` but the user will see the name as `link.jpg` in Explorer because .lnk is a special extension that is hidden.
- A symbolic link (symlink). These are links on the filesystem level and can have any extension. `mklink "c:\mylink.jpg" "c:\file.jpg"`
- A hardlink. This is another name for the same file (alias), it does not create a shortcut. `mklink /H "c:\anothername.jpg" "c:\file.jpg"`

Comment: To use the mklink executable, a console must be run as Administrator. I also had to remove the .exe extension (so 'mklink' alone).

Comment: @WildPottok You can create a hardlink without admin rights. If you turn the developer mode on you can probably do it with symlinks as well.

Comment: I cannot use mklink anymore, neither in a normal nor an admin powershell window. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/creating-hard-and-soft-links-using-powershell for instructions using New-Item with -ItemType SymbolicLink